# How to backup and restore Virtual machine OS?

Tags: backup, virtual-machine

In VM ware Virtual machine i have installed the Centos in Window 7.Now i want to re install my Window 7 but i do not want to loose my virtual machine Centos. I Google many time for this topic but did not find any helpful information.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your virtual machine is saved under the form of multiple files, which you can easily back-up on an external hard-drive, or in the cloud. If you are using VMWare, then your machine will be split into `.vmdk`, `.vmx`, `.vmxf`, `.vmsd` and `.nvram` files, depending on your VM configuration.

Just check where you store the VM files, and back them up before re-installing the host system. Afterwards, just import the `.vmx` file back into VMWare.

In VMWare Player right-click on your VM, go to Settings, then Options, and under Working Directory you should see where your VM files are stored. Just back-up that entire folder before reinstalling.

Comment: In C:/ProgramFiles i have VMware folder and in it i have many files.

Comment: What are you using - VMWare Workstation or VMWare Player?

Comment: VMWare Player.I checked the folder there is no such file like .vmx.Where i found this file?

Comment: Are backup methods different for VMWare Workstation and VMWare Player? I did not find any such file that you have mentioned above.

Comment: No solution for my problem? @Peter Noble